# Can't login with a Mac user but I can manage system preferences with that account

Tags: macos, user-accounts

I came to office and started my Mac. The admin user (tolga) I use everyday was not in the login screen list.

Here's what I tried:

1. I logged in with my other (non-admin) account. Opened **Settings > Users & Groups**.
2. I opened **Login Options** with my admin account (tolga), strangely it accepted the password to modify settings.
3. I changed setting to display name and password, tried to login from login screen with tolga, still couldn't login.
4. My login account (tolga) is there. It says (Admin, Mobile) - I don't know what mobile means. Unlike other admin accounts, I can't change password of tolga either. ()
5. I checked **Security & Privacy > Filevault**, it's off

I can see /Users/Tolga

**More**: Previous week I installed [Munki from Github](https://github.com/munki/munki). It's the first time I restarted for a week. Would the problem be related with this?

What's my chance to login with tolga account again?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer.

on **Settings > Users & Groups** I checked **Allow network users to log in at login window** than I was able to login. Not a good solution, but I can access my account for now.